# Windows 8 wrong drive letter causing issues

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, acronis-trueimage

I used a USB stick to clone a malfunctioning OS drive onto a working drive with Acronis through a boot run.

However the new drive isn't getting the 'C' label and this is making Windows 8 receive a black screen when I try and log in. Therefore I can't change the drive letter to C.

How do I force the new drive to have its rightful C?

Comment: Not clear. Please edit your question: *what* did you copy to *what* using Acronis? Then you rebooted, I assume?

Comment: Windows Recovery Console should be able to resolve a problem like this have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the recovery disk of Windows you can use that and boot from cd/DVD. Windows 8 has an option to open `cmd`.

Use `diskpart` in cmd to change the drive letter to c.

1. enter `diskpart`: type in cmd `diskpart`
2. type `list vol` and hit enter
3. select the volume you whant to change the drive letter by typing this: `select vol (your vol here)`
4. then to change drive letter to c type in: `assign letter=C`
5. Exit diskpart by typing `exit`
6. Exit `cmd` by typing `exit`

That should do it.

For more INFO: [Change drive letter](http://adhirmondal.com/how-to-change-drive-letter-using-command-prompt-on-windows-7/)